# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, vb.net, schedule

Please help, im trying to build a classroom scheduling system, so the system is almost complete, i can debug the system but whenever i go to set some schedules, it shows this kind of message

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException:

> 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near ''SELECT subj.sub_code, subj.sub_desc, start_time, end_time,
> days, item_color, pr' at line 1'

What should I do? Please help. heres the part of the code that im guessing that it has a problem

```
Dim constring As String = "server=localhost;user id='root';password='!Password123';database = 'scheduling'"
Using con As New MySqlConnection(constring)
    sql = "'SELECT subj.sub_code, subj.sub_desc, start_time, end_time, days, item_color, pr_id, sched.sched_id, sched.course_id FROM tblschedule AS sched INNER JOIN open_subjects AS op_sub ON sched.sub_code = op_sub.sub_code INNER JOIN subject AS subj ON op_sub.sub_code = subj.sub_code WHERE sched.room_id ='" & room_id & "' AND op_sub.semester = '" & school_semester_text & "' AND op_sub.sy = '" & school_year_text & "' AND sched.void = 0 '"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Using ds As New DataSet()
            sda.Fill(ds, "tblschedule")
            Using dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("tblschedule")
```

Comment: You have a sql injection issue. Always use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation. Apart from that, why you use `''` areound your select statement?

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Dim constring As String = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=########;database=scheduling"
Dim sql As String = "
SELECT subj.sub_code, subj.sub_desc, start_time, end_time, days, item_color, pr_id, sched.sched_id, sched.course_id 
FROM tblschedule AS sched 
INNER JOIN open_subjects AS op_sub ON sched.sub_code = op_sub.sub_code
INNER JOIN subject AS subj ON op_sub.sub_code = subj.sub_code 
WHERE sched.room_id = @room_id AND op_sub.semester = @semester AND op_sub.sy = @year AND sched.void = 0
"

Dim dt As New DataTabe()
Using con As New MySqlConnection(constring), _
      cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, con), _
      sda As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@room_id", room_id)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@semester", school_semester_text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", school_year_text)
    sda.Fill(dt)
End Using
```

Note how I used the parameters instead of string concatenation. This is how you must do it if you don't want your application to end up horribly hacked.

Comment: Not forgetting [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), of course ;)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't really use MySql often myself, but I have it on good authority from people I trust that MySql handles parameter binding differently, and it's much less of a concern than with Sql Server.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thanks, that's interesting information. (If it had been otherwise, I thought you might have taken the opportunity to put quotes around the parameter names.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Well the quotes around the names was an oversite (now corrected).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Does MySql not use the size of string parameters for its query cache? Is there a written authoritative article on MySql parameter binding that I could peruse, please?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't have anything handy, sorry.